# Maximization problem

Tags: optimization, randomized-algorithms

I work at a company and i got to a seminar we're they told us to solve this problem below in the picture [image]

Is there an algorithm that can help me solve this question.
I thought about a randomized algorithm after that i get stuck?

Comment: Choose a random assignment.

Comment: You can derandomize this algorithm using the method of conditional expectations.

Comment: When $k=2$, better algorithms are known, and the problem is quite famous.

Comment: Yuval Filmus can you give a link to this famous problem and solution to it?

Comment: It’s called “MAX-CUT”, and there’s plenty of information on it out there.

Comment: Thanks Yuval Filmus :)!

Comment: Yuval Filmus Why is this MAX-CUT problem what is your motivations??

Comment: @mire12 Please do not delete a question once someone has given an useful reply, we generally want to keep your question and any useful replies even after your problem has been solved, in order to help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).  Please give proper attribution to the source of all copied material!

Comment: I wanted to delete this question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $k \ge n$ is trivial as you can give different value to every variable, which satisfy all inequalities and thus is optimal. So let's consider $k < n$.

This problem can be considered as building a paritition of the $n$ variables in $k$ subsets. All inequalities involving two variables in the same subset are unsatisfied, any other is satisfied.
I would first build an efficient structure to count the number of inequalities involving each pair of variables. Basically this is a $n^2$ array, built in $O(m)$. In case $m << n$, a graph may be more efficient than a sparse matrix.

Then, let's take arbitrarily $k$ variables and distribute them into the $k$ subsets (give them the $k$ different values). Any inequalities involving these first variables is satisfied (then the arbitrarily may target greedily the largest values in the array).

Then loop on the remaining variables. For each $x_i$, evaluate $A^i_k$, the number of unsatisfied inequalities (considering only the variables assigned so far), for each of the $k$ possible assignment. For this, one has to consider every assigned variable in the same subset, this step is $O(n)$.

Let's call $S_i = \sum_k A^i_k$.

By assigning $k_0$ to $x_i$,

you unsatisfy $A^i_{k_0}$ inequalities but satisfy $S_i - A^i_{k_0}$ ones.

So by picking $k_0$ that minimizes $A^i_{k_0}$, you unsatisfy at most $S/k$ inequalities, satisying at least $S(1-1/k)$ others. So overall you guarantee to satisfy $m(1-1/k)$ inequalities (and clearly $(1-1/k)OPT$ ones).

This achieves $O(m + n^2)$ in time and $O(n^2)$ in space.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as MAX-$k$-CUT, a generalization of the well-known MAX-CUT problem. A recent paper on the topic is Alantha Newman, [Complex semidefinite programming and Max-$k$-Cut](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/8309/pdf/OASIcs-SOSA-2018-13.pdf).

The classic algorithm of Goemans and Williamson gives a (roughly) 0.878 approximation for MAX-CUT (the case $k=2$ of your problem), which is tight assuming Khot's Unique Games Conjecture. The best possible approximation ratio (assuming the Unique Games Conjecture) for $k > 2$ is not yet known, as far as I understand, but it is known to be better than $1-1/k$ for all $k$.

A random assignment satisfies in expectation a $1-1/k$ fraction of the constraints, and in particular gives a $1-1/k$ approximation in expectation. This algorithm can be derandomized using the method of conditional expectations, as well as using the greedy approach outlined in Optidad's answer.